# Lambda Calculus inductive substitution definition

Tags: lambda-calculus, induction

I'm reading **Lambda-Calculus and Combinators: An Introduction**, and there's the following definition of $\lambda$-substitution:

- $FV(P)$ stands for the set containing all free-variables from $P$.

> **Definition 1.12 (Substitution)** For any $M, N, x$, define $[N/x]M$ to be the result of substituting $N$ for every free occurrence of $x$ in $M$, and changing bound variables to avoid clashes. The precise definition is by induction on $M$, as follows ***(after [CF58, p.94])***.
>
> (a) $[N/x]x \equiv N$
>
> (b) $[N/x]a \equiv a$ for all atoms $a \not \equiv x$
>
> (c) $[N/x](PQ) \equiv ([N/x]P)([N/x]Q)$
>
> (d) $[N/x](\lambda x.P) \equiv (\lambda x.P)$
>
> (e) $[N/x](\lambda y.P) \equiv P$ if $x \not \in FV(P)$.
>
> (f) $[N/x](\lambda y.P) \equiv \lambda y. [N/x]P$ if $x \in FV(P)$ and $y \not \in FV(N)$.
>
> (g) $[N/x](\lambda y.P) \equiv \lambda z. [N/x][z/y]P$ if $x \in FV(P)$ and $y \in FV(N)$.

I do understand that:

- $(a), (b)$ are the base cases for this induction.
- $(d)$ exists per definition, as one is not allowed to substitute bound variables.
- $(g)$ prevents a bound variable from changing to a free one. It does this by first substituting a **bound variable**.

My question is: **If one deletes $(d)$ and allows bound variables to be substituted, is $(g)$ strong enough to handle it without messing up everything?**

I'm asking this because $(d)$ seems to prevent the following $\alpha$-equivalent substitutions.

$$ [y/x] ~~ \lambda x. x \equiv \lambda y.y $$

Comment: "*(g) prevents a bound variable from changing to a free one*" - It's the other way around: (g) prevents *capturing* of a free $y$ (it's free in $N$).

Comment: Thanks, that comment really cleared some of my doubts. I was reading (g) the wrong way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "If one deletes $(\mathrm{d})$ and allows bound variables to be substituted..."

The problem here is that *substitution* of a bound variable makes little sense, since one substitutes a variable (let's forget for a moment it should be free) with a *term*, which may very well be an abstraction or application, but not a variable.

Let me illustrate this by example. What if we are trying to substitute a bound variable with a term, which is not a variable? Like this:
$$[(y\; y)\ / \ x]\ \lambda x. x.$$
What should we do?

- Produce $\lambda (y\; y). (y\; y)$? It is not a well-formed term, so the answer is no.
- Another choice would be to leave the binding instance intact and make $\lambda x. (y\; y)$ a result. Let's not take into account if it makes sense, at least it is syntactically correct. This variant causes us major troubles too: it will mess up scopes and render $\beta$-reduction useless. And our end goal is to define $\beta$-reduction via substitution.

> $(\mathrm{g})$ prevents a bound variable from changing to a free one. It does this by first substituting a bound variable.

It does not use substitution, it uses renaming, which is a different notion.

> "...is $(\mathrm{g})$ strong enough to handle it without messing up everything?"

$(\mathrm{g})$ does not tell us anything about substitution of bound variables, since it has the condition $x \in \mathrm{FV}(P)$

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you can't always define a substitution for bound variables. Having $[x/y](\lambda y.\ y) = \lambda x.\ x$ may look appealing, but there's no real way to replace the bound variable in $[(xx)/y](\lambda y.\ y)$ since $\lambda$ wants a variable, not a term. (As Anton Trunov points out above)

It is true however that the $\lambda$ rules in the definition of substitution $(d,e,f,g)$ consider a lot of cases, which could be combined at the cost of a few more $\alpha$-conversions. For instance, we could replace all the $\lambda$ rules with this one:
$$
\qquad [N/x](\lambda y.\ P) = (\lambda z.\ [N/x][z/y]P)
\qquad \mbox{where $z$ is the first variable not free in $x N (\lambda y.\ P)$}
$$
This rule *always* renames bound variables to fresh ones, even when it is not necessary to do so. Moreover, it *always* distributes the substitution inside the lambda, even when $x \notin FV(P)$ and the substitution has no effect.

The result of the rule above is the same of what you get using rules $(d,e,f,g)$ up to $\alpha$-conversion. Hence, it only differs from the rules in the book by performing more renamings.

Rules $(d,e,f,g)$ can be seen as a "smarter" way of performing substitution, stopping as soon as there is no more $x$ around, and renaming variables only as needed.